# Css Media query not working with Spring framework

Tags: java, html, css, spring, jsp

I have built a webpage which works fine & is responsive,
but when I use the same files with the Spring framework, the webpage doesn't appear to be responsive.

I have checked the responsiveness of the Spring webpage by opening the webpage in mobile & also using chrome's inspect mode.

Please let me know if any more details is needed.

HTML File

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<title>URL Shortner</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>



<div class="s130">

<form:form action="show" method="POST" onsubmit=" return continueornot();">
  <h1>Short URL </h1>
  <p>Paste your Long URL here</p>
    <div class="inner-form">
        <div class="input-field first-wrap">
        <div class="svg-wrapper">
          
        </div>
            <input class="input-tag" id="search" type="text" name="longUrl" placeholder="Paste your Link here!" />
        </div>
        <div class="input-field second-wrap">
            <input class="btn lco" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
     <span id="error"></span>
    <h2 id="urlerror">${link}</h2>
</form:form>
<footer>
</footer>


</div>

<script>
function validateEmail(email) { 
var re = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
return re.test(email);
} 
function continueornot() {
if(validateEmail(document.getElementById('search').value)){
// ok
}else{  urlerror.innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>"+
"Please enter a valid URL!</span>"
return false;}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

MY CSS

```
body{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fbfbfb, #cfc0c0);
    color: #ffffff;
}

.container{
margin-left:20px;
}
h1{
    font-size: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    color: #1f1f1f;
    font-family: "montserrat";
}

h2{
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "montserrat";
}

span{
    color: #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 400;
    font-weight: 900;
}

p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}



.btn{
margin: auto;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #1f1f1f;
    border-radius: 0.6em;
    color: #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 1.2em 2.5em;
    cursor: grab;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "montserrat";
    font-weight: 900;
}

.btn:hover{
    color:#ffffff;
    outline: 0;
}

.lco{
    transition: box-shadow 300ms ease-in-out, color 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.lco:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 40px 40px #1f1f1f inset;
}

.input-tag{
    display: block;
    margin : 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius:15px;
    width:50%;
    height:25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:inherit;
    box-shadow:0 0 15px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    h1{
        font-size: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 12%;
        margin-bottom: 12%;
        color: #1f1f1f;
        font-family: "montserrat";
    }
    p{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 40%;
       
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        color: #1f1f1f;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 25px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 8%;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        color: #1f1f1f;
        font-family: "montserrat";
    }
    .btn{
        background-color: transparent;
        margin-top: 7%;
        border: 2px solid #1f1f1f;
        border-radius: 0.6em;
        color: #1f1f1f;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 200;
        padding: 0.5em 1.5em;
        cursor: grab;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: "montserrat";
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    .input-tag{
        display: block;
        margin : 0px auto;
        margin-top: 10%;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius:15px;
        width:70%;
        height:24px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family:inherit;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow:0 0 15px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
    }
   
}
```

Project structure:

[image: Project Structure image]

Comment: Where is the css file located? What's your project dir structure like?

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal I have attached the project structure above. Please check.  [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2LT0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

To run @media query in your spring boot css file you should use min-width
replace of max-width then it will run good

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).